# Is there a French expression for "No man's land"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, anglicismes

I just saw "No man's land" used in English in a French text, and that made we wonder, just out of curiosity, whether there's an equivalent phrase in French.  My image of "No man's land" is of the area between two trenches, particularly during the first world war. How would you translate that literal definition into French? Wiktionary includes the following:

> No man's land: (Militaire) Zone entre deux frontières, entre deux
>   fronts, où toute présence humaine est considérée comme une agression
>   et entraine sa suppression par l’une ou l’autre des armées.

Is there no shorter expression / phrase?  What would a French person have a said a century ago?

---

Je viens de voir "No man's land" utilisé en anglais dans un texte français.  Existe-t-il une expression équivalente?

Comment: If you wait a year or two, a French person a century before that would have said *no man's land* ;)

Comment: *No man's land* est entré dans le langage usuel. Selon les circonstances c'est parfois une *Zone démilitarisée*.

Comment: Yes, there is and it's “no man's land”. Why would you think it's not French or needs to be “translated”?

Comment: @Relaxed I was just curious: as I wrote above, I was wondering whether there's an equivalent phrase in French. I never wrote that the phrase "needs" to be translated -- what gave you that idea?

Comment: @Adrian I got this idea from the question “How would you translate that literal definition into French?” which I might have misunderstood myself. But to reiterate, the way to express that *in French* is “no man's land”. “No man's land” is not merely an English phrase, it's also the equivalent phrase in French.

Comment: That agrees with what cl-r said above: "No man's land est entré dans le langage usuel."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

L'expression *No man's land*, apparue en anglais au moyen-âge pour désigner un lieu d'exécution au nord de Londres a ensuite été utilisée pour désigner un terrain vague non habité. Le terme est apparu en anglais dans son sens militaire actuel en 1908 dans une œuvre de fiction anglaise sur la guerre*, et a commencé à être utilisé en relation avec la situation sur le front de la guerre 14-18. Après la guerre il s'est largement répandu en français. Il n'est entrée dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie qu'après 1956 parce qu'on trouve cette citation de Charles Müller dans sa revue *La classe de français* (mars-avril 1956) p.174.

> « Dans le *no man's land* (le mot n'est pas dans les dictionnaires mais il faudra bien l'y admettre un jour, car il est adopté, et le français ne lui oppose aucune création propre, à ma connaissance), dans le *no man's land*, dis-je, où s'affrontent parfois les puristes et leurs adversaires, à cette limite imprécise entre le langage correct et le babarisme, se trouve une position souvent disputée [...] (…) »
>   Charles Muller, in la Classe de français, mai-juin 1956.

Il est classé encore comme anglicisme dans la plupart des dictionnaires. 
La banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec propose [plusieurs équivalents](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=no+man%27s+land&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) qu'on rencontre parfois dans la presse, comme « zone neutre » par exemple.

---

- Voir [référence](http://1914-1918.invisionzone.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=25236&p=199699) dans ce blog sur la Guerre 14 (en anglais).

Comment: To add: Additionally, OP can check [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/) if you are looking for translations as such in standard Canadian French. For example, [the entry for no man's land](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=NO%20MAN%20LAND). **N.B.:** These translations, found in this government database, may not be understood by people in other French-speaking regions, such as France. Standard Canadian French is considered a part of International Standard French, but this gap still remains.

Comment: Pour moi un *no man's land* est un espace sans présence humaine. Cette définition est-elle erronée ? (le wiktionary ne mentionne pas ce sens)

Answer (score 12):

Le sens, et donc la traduction, dépendent du contexte.

Le mot est apparu en français pour désigner l'espace entre 2 tranchées.  Dans ce contexte, utiliser un autre terme serait du snobisme. Wikipédia ne donne d'ailleurs pas de traduction.

De nos jours, la plupart des usages sont des hyperboles. Il suffit donc de dé-métaphoriser.
Selon le contexte c'est :

- un désert
- une zone d'exclusion
- une zone démilitarisée
- une terre vierge
- une terra incognita
- une zone interdite
- une zone insalubre/toxique
- une boîte lesbienne
- etc...